# Error message while trying to launch approval from apex plugin from Visual Workflow - NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS

Tags: apex, visualforce, approval-process

I've seen others with similar problems, but not a lot of solutions. I have created an approval process that has no filters on entering or restrictions, and am calling it like so from an apex plugin which is called from visual Workflow...

```
    Id callProspectingTask = (Id)request.inputParameters.get('callProspectingTask');

    // Create an approval request for the Task
    Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest approvalRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest(); 
    approvalRequest.setComments('Testing ...'); 
    approvalRequest.setObjectId(callProspectingTask);
    Approval.ProcessResult approvalResult = Approval.process(approvalRequest);
```

I have tried it with setnextApprover.Ids set, without them set,etc.
The input task id is correct, but I always get:

NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS :No applicable process found!

I'm pretty much a Salesforce newbie, so perhaps I am missing something.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that `callProspectingTask` is an Id to the correct record that you want the approval process to run on? Have you tried running the approval process through a standard layout via the "Submit for Approval" button to verify that the process does work?

Comment: Hey - yes, the ID is correct. Have not tried the standard layout approach - good idea - I'll give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: As stupid as it sounds - is the approval process activated?

Comment: Yes, it is activated - at this point, nothing sounds stupid - thanks :-)